# How to retrieve another user's MS Teams chats with the Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

As a global administrator I'm attempting to retrieve the list of MS Teams chats for a different user, however no matter which id I pass to `GET /beta/users/{id}/chats` the response is always the list of chats for the authenticated user. How do you get the list of chats for a different user?

The API documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) suggests that I should be able to call `GET /beta/me/chats` to retrieve the list of my chats and `GET /beta/users/{id}/chats` to retrieve the list of someone else's chats.

Through experimentation I've noticed that I can pass any string for {id} and the request always succeeds with response `200 OK`, but with my list of chats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieving the list of chats that another user is a part of isn't currently supported, that's why Application level permissions aren't supported.

Comment: Is there a plan to support this functionality at some point?  How is an organization meant to perform eDiscovery for MS Teams if an administrator cannot access their employee's chats?

Comment: To add to this: the Graph API already allows us to read all of the email messages for another user.  Why are chats considered more secure in this way?  It will allow for content and communication within an organization to not be exportable for legal review.